# Reverse string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a code for example:- ABCDEFGHIJKL
I need the output as LKJIHGFEDCBA in SQL Server 2005.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions/ideas.

Comment: @FuzzyTree Not really because that one demanded a set based solution rather than just using the inbuilt operator as would be sensible.

Comment: @MartinSmith is the built in operator available in sql server 2005?

Comment: @FuzzyTree Yes it's available and is used in the question itself there. Think they were just curious to see if it could be done in a set based way without using it though!

Comment: Ah, you're right. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx) threw me off because it says `Applies to SQL Server 2008 through current version` but I see there's a link to SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select reverse('ABCDEFGHIJKL')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms180040.aspx) function to reverse a string.

```
select reverse('ABCDEFGHIJKL') reverseString

Output will be

reverseString
LKJIHGFEDCBA

or    

SELECT FirstName, REVERSE(FirstName) AS Reverse
    FROM Person.Person
    WHERE BusinessEntityID < 5
    ORDER BY FirstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
SELECT REVERSE ('YOURFIELDNAME') AS ReverseString FROM 'YOURTABLE'

REVERSE is a SQL function which will return string containing reverse string of parameter's string.
```

for more help please check

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=84A7FBB8-D134-482A-8A6A-EA4E660ED51B&tkw=uses-of-the-reverse-string-function